# Split youtube url rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, youtube

I m trying to parse youtube url. At this time my code is ok with standard youtube url.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYMFIIVOHyo
```

But don't work with list or youtu.be like this

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYMFIIVOHyo&list=UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw
https://youtu.be/tYMFIIVOHyo?list=UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw
https://youtu.be/tYMFIIVOHyo
```

My code is

```
module CampingsHelper
  def embed(youtube_url)
   youtube_id = youtube_url.split("=").last
   content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{youtube_id}")
 end
```

How I can fix this ?

By the way I want to show an alert if url isn't from youtube.

Comment: Your code is assuming that the parameter you want is last. Don't do that. You need to take apart the query and then access the specific parameter's value you want. URL queries can change order and when they do assuming you want the last one will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
youtube_id = youtube_url[/(?<=v=)[^&]+|(?<=https:\/\/youtu.be\/)[^&?]+/]
```

To show an alert can just check that URL doesn't start with `https://www.youtube.com`, `https://youtube.com` or `https://youtu.be`

Comment: First : Thanks a lot it's work ! For my alert, I understand the method, but i use form for putting youtube url like this  <%= f.text_field :youtube_url, class:"form-control" %> and i don't know how i can do this

Comment: You need some front-end (client side) JavaScript validation. I cannot recommend a specific solution, sorry.

Comment: Dont worry, i will search. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't doing the right thing, which would be to use the existing wheel that comes with Ruby called [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYMFIIVOHyo&list=UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw')
uri.host # => "www.youtube.com"
uri.query # => "v=tYMFIIVOHyo&list=UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw"
uri.query && URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"v"=>"tYMFIIVOHyo", "list"=>"UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw"}
uri.query && URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h['list'] # => "UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw"

uri = URI.parse('https://youtu.be/tYMFIIVOHyo?list=UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw')
uri.host # => "youtu.be"
uri.query # => "list=UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw"
uri.query && URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"list"=>"UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw"}
uri.query && URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h['list'] # => "UUH3V-b6weBfTrDuyJgFioOw"

uri = URI.parse('https://youtu.be/tYMFIIVOHyo')
uri.host # => "youtu.be"
uri.query # => nil
uri.query && URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => nil
uri.query && URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h['list'] # => nil
```

URI understands the specification and has the tools to make it easy to take apart and build URIs. You can try building your own but odds are really good you'll miss something so take advantage of the well-tested library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I m using code form @Oleksandr it's works perfectly.

Comment: It will work until YouTube changes the order of the URL's parameters and/or adds an additional query parameter that has a value. I'd really recommend not taking the short-cut. They rarely work in the long run.